# Google App Engine java replace jpa @OneToMany/@ManyToOne with objectify

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I have an existing google app engine java application runs with jpa and now i am trying to move to objectify for many different purposes.

Current application has the below representation of the entities.

```
Class Parent{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="parent")
    private List<Child> childs = null;
}

Class Child{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;

    @ManyToOne  
    private Parent parent;

}
```

How can i get the above representation in Objectify? I am using objectify4.
I have seen @Parent, but it seems not possible to load the list of child entities directly while fetching a parent?

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my own problem. Here is the code.

https://github.com/rameshv1210/objectify-many-to-one/

Answer (score 2):

Objectify uses different [concepts](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts) than relational data stores and ORMs. Relations are constructed using `Key`s and are not loaded automatically. You can read about the modelling of relationships in Objectify [here](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/IntroductionToObjectify#Relationships). The `@Parent` relationship is [something special](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/BestPractices#Avoid_@Parent) and is not the one relevant for 1:n or n:m relationships.

So basically you have

```
class Parent {
    Key<Child>[] childs;
}

class Child {
    Key<Parent> parent;
}
```

And then you would get the entities via the Objectfy service, e.g.

```
Parent aParent = ofy.get(aChild.parent);
```

There are no lazily loaded collections. If you want to construct a set of objects you need to do it explicitely.

Comment: Thanks for your response, is it possible to fetch the child entities from parent without storing child keys/references in parent.

Comment: Associations are expressed by `Key`s so you need them in either `Parent` or `Child`. If you have them in both you create a bidirectional association which is harder to maintain and often not very useful. You can let go of the `Key` array in `Parent`. Then you just need Objectify's methods for filtering to get all `Child` objects with a specific `Parent`s `Key`. This is especially useful if you have a large number of children that should be filtered further by certain criteria or paging.

Comment: But How does JPA works without storing keys either in parent or child? My existing GAE java application uses JPA and i see datastore doesn't have any key stored in either child or parent. And it has only parent child relationship no keys are stored in both parent or child. My changes now should not effect the existing database. How can i do it. Thanks for your detailed explination.